# JQuery to capture form (not html form) data and send to another location

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

First of all, pardon my complete lack of skills.

We have a website with a simple slide-in form (appears if clicked on by the user) that sends us a request to return a call to the user. We request name, email, phone number and time of the call.

The data is sent through `$.post` to another php file, but there isn't any `<form>` tag in the html, only `<input>` tags. So I assumed the JS/JQuery (I don't know what to call it) is capturing and sending the data that is typed in the input fields.

I need to gather all these inputs (except for time) and send it to a API of a marketing service provider we contracted.

So, this is what the form does for now:

The first part is what is actually necessary

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#G4_Envia').click(function() {
        var Nome = $('#g4_nome').val();
        var Email = $('#g4_email').val();
        var Telefone = $('#g4_telefone').val();
        var Horario = $('#g4_horario').val();
```

The second part is not relevant, but I put it here if someone needs it.

```
if (Nome != '' && Email != '' && Telefone != '' && Horario != '')
        {
            $('.liga_form').hide(300);
            $('.liga_wait').show(300);

            $.post("<?=$URL_BASE?>Paginas/G4Liga/Acoes/Envia.php", {nome: Nome, email: Email, telefone: Telefone, horario: Horario}, function() {
                $('.liga_wait').hide(300);
                $('.liga_done').show(300);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And right after this script, begins the "fake" form:

```
<div class="cursos-categorias boletim">
<hgroup>
    <h2>G4 Liga para você</h2>
    <h4 class="boletimTexto">Deixe seu nome e telefone nos campos abaixo e ligaremos para você.</h4>
</hgroup>
<div class="g4_liga">
    <div class="liga_form">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="g4_nome" class="inputHome" placeholder="Nome"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="text" id="g4_email" class="inputHome" placeholder="E-Mail"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="text" id="g4_telefone" class="inputHome stdmask-phone" placeholder="Telefone"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="text" id="g4_horario" class="inputHome stdmask-hora" placeholder="Horário de preferência"/>
        </div>

        <button id="G4_Envia" class="btHome">Enviar</button>
    </div>

    <div class="liga_wait">
        <b>Aguarde,</b><br/>
        solicitação em andamento
    </div>

    <div class="liga_done">
        Solicitação Enviada
    </div>
</div>
```

After that, I have to load the service provider script:

```
<script type ='text/javascript' src="https://d335luupugsy2.cloudfront.net/js/integration/stable/rd-js-integration.min.js"></script>
```

So, the provider instructed me to put this code structure right after (this is just an example):

```
<script type ='text/javascript'>
    var data_array = [
        { name: 'email', value: 'integracao@test.com' },
        { name: 'identificador', value: 'YOUR_IDENTIFIER_HERE' },
        { name: 'token_rdstation', value: 'YOUR_TOKEN_HERE' },
        { name: 'nome', value: 'Test' }
    ];
 RdIntegration.post(data_array, function () { alert('callback'); });
</script>
```

Being `RdIntegration` the function provided that does the sending of data.

And I wrote this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var data_array = [
    { name: 'nome', value: Nome },
    { name: 'email', value: Email },
    { name: 'telefone', value: Telefone },
    { name: 'token_rdstation', value: '5535eb5bc797b015477039eddba3c803' },
    { name: 'identificador', value: 'G4-liga' }
 ];
 RdIntegration.post(data_array);
```

And it didn't work.

Am I doing something wrong with the values? Should I put it inside the first script?

Sorry for the stupidity and the long post, but I hope I could explain well.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You could try to start debuging. write a few console.log() like: console.log(Nome); console.log(Email), console.log(RdIntegration); etc to see if you have data on it. and you could change this line RdIntegration.post(data_array); to RdIntegration.post(data_array, function(evt){alert(evt);}); to see whats happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, you just need to put the integration from your provider just after the current form send the form data.

```
$.post("<?=$URL_BASE?>Paginas/G4Liga/Acoes/Envia.php", {nome: Nome, email: Email, telefone: Telefone, horario: Horario}, function() {
    $('.liga_wait').hide(300);
    $('.liga_done').show(300);
    // put your integration here....
});
```

So, your final code could looks like this:

```
$.post("<?=$URL_BASE?>Paginas/G4Liga/Acoes/Envia.php", {nome: Nome, email: Email, telefone: Telefone, horario: Horario}, function() {
    $('.liga_wait').hide(300);
    $('.liga_done').show(300);

    var data_array = [
        { name: 'nome', value: Nome },
        { name: 'email', value: Email },
        { name: 'telefone', value: Telefone },
        { name: 'token_rdstation', value: '5535eb5bc797b015477039eddba3c803' },
        { name: 'identificador', value: 'G4-liga' }
     ];
    RdIntegration.post(data_array);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use jQuery's [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) function to encode the input values into an object array and then post via your custom class method.

```
var data_array = $('.liga_form :input').serializeArray();
RdIntegration.post(data_array);
```

Edit Note: this will only work if your inputs have a name attribute.